# How do I split the parameters from a received function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, currying

I need to write a definition for the following function:

```
f :: c -> (c -> a -> b) -> (a, [a]) -> ([b], b)
```

which receives an element c and a function g (which is (c->a->b)).

```
f c g = ???
```

So it seems to me that this function g receives a c and returns a function that receives an a and returns a b. It could be a function that receives a c and an a and returns a b, but then where would the a come from?

```
f :: c -> (c -> (a -> b)) -> (a, [a]) -> ([b], b)
```

So I have c which I can feed into g and get back the function (a->b). How do I split those in order to return the tuples (a, [a]) and ([b], b)?

Comment: `(a,[a])` is an argument, not the return type.

Comment: You've already figured out that you have to apply `g` to `c`, and that `g`'s `a` argument should probably come from the `(a, [a])` tuple. Without a specification of what `f` should do with that tuple we can't really give you any more advice than that. I suspect writing down (in words) a precise specification of `f`'s behaviour will empower you to implement it without our help anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Sans any list reordering (including dropping and duplicating elements, possibly depending on the list length), the only viable implementation is `f c g = let h = g c in \(x, xs) -> (map h xs, h x)`

Comment: @Bergi Depends what you mean by "list reordering". It wouldn't be unreasonable to claim that `\(x, xs) -> let ys = map h (x:xs) in (init ys, last ys)` doesn't reorder its input

Comment: I don't know why this question was downvoted. OP is clearly making an attempt to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation is

```
f c g = \(x, xs) -> (map (g c) xs, (g c) x)
```

Thank you, @Bergi.

Comment: @chepner It is, but he forgot a newline, which made SO think the code block was just a continuation of the text before, which made it swallow a backslash as starting an escape rather than as a literal chunk of code. I inserted a newline for him, and now you can see what he really meant.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, a,b and c are types not values, for example the function id (which receives an argument and returns it with no changes made Ex:`id 4` is 4) has the type signature:

`id :: c -> c`

That means that it receives a parameter of type c and returns a value of type c.
So, what does the following type signature mean ?

`func :: a -> b -> b`

It means that `func` receives two arguments, one of type a and one of type b, and returns a value of type b because **only the last type is the return type**.
If you want a function that returns a function it would look something like this:

`func2 :: a -> (b-> b)`

`func2` takes a value of type a and returns a function that it turn takes a value of type b and returns a value of type b.
So the type signature of f (`f :: c -> (c -> (a -> b)) -> (a, [a]) -> ([b], b)`) shows us that f takes 3 arguments : one of type c, one that is a function which takes a type c value and returns a function that in turn takes a value of type a and returns a value of type b,another one which is a tuple (a pair in this case) consisting of a value of type a and a list of values which have type a and finally returns a tuple consisting of a list of values which have type b and a value of type b. 
Also, `[a]` means a list of type a values and `(a1,a2....an)` is a tuple (kinda like a list with fixed size), `(a,b)` specifically is a pair consisting of a value of type a and a value of type b.

Comment: `a -> b -> b` is the same type as `a -> (b -> b)`. I don't understand why you're going to such trouble to differentiate them.

Comment: @amalloy I forgot that haskell type signatures were right associative, a better example would have been `func2 :: (a -> b) -> b`.

Comment: Continuing from what @amalloy said, there isn't really a distinction in Haskell between "a function that takes two arguments" and "a function that takes in one argument and returns a function that takes in one argument" (technically, all functions in Haskell take exactly one argument, but the first statement is sometimes used as a shorthand).